# Retrieving data from two tables and to show the data on same page using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

Greetings from the core of my heart!
I am using Laravel v-5.6. I am trying to retrieve data from two tables and to show them on same page. I am using two controllers and two models. And the tables has no relation.
**Note**: subcondetails is the view where I want to show the data

1st Controller Name: PostController
Using it to retrieve data from DB. Table name is subcontractors
Code:

```php
public function index()
{
    $subcontractors = DB::select('select * from subcontractors');
    return view('subcondetails', ['subcontractors' => $subcontractors]);
}
```

2nd Controller Name: SubemController
Using it to retrieve data from DB. Table name is subemployees
Code:

```php
public function index()
{
    $subemployees = DB::select('select * from subemployees');
    return view('subcondetails', ['subemployees' => $subemployees]);
}
```

Now to show the data on same page the following code **works fine** for **first controller**

```html
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($subcontractors as $subcontractor)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $subcontractor->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $subcontractor->companyname }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

But on the same page when I try to load table it gives an error **Undefined Variable** '*subemployees*'
Code is as:

```html
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    
        <tbody>
          @foreach($subemployees as $subemployee)
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ $subemployee->id }}</td>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
```

My web (routes) file code is as:

```php
    Route::get('/', 'PostController@index');
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

I created second controller 'SubempController' using this code

```sh
    php artisan make:controller SubempController --resource
```

My code from migrations for first table is as:

```php
Schema::create('subcontractors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('branches');
    $table->string('companyname');
    $table->string('companyaddress');
    $table->string('contactperson');
    $table->integer('contactnumber');
    $table->string('contactdepartment');
    $table->string('emailaddress');
    $table->string('invoiceterms');
    $table->text('paymentterms');
    $table->integer('vatregistration')->nullable();
    $table->integer('payrate');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

2nd Table:

```php
Schema::create('subemployees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('staff_name');
    $table->integer('contact_number');
    $table->integer('sia_number')->nullable();
    $table->string('sia_type')->nullable();
    $table->date('my_date')->nullable();
    $table->date('my_date2');
    $table->integer('ni_number');
    $table->string('training_name');
    $table->integer('certificate_number');
    $table->string('address1');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I would like to have a solution for it. If you require any information please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your route is using the the `index` method at the`PostController`. It returns the view `subcondetails`, passing the `subcontractors` variable, but not the `subemployees`.

You must query both resources using the same controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $subemployees = DB::select('select * from subemployees');
    $subcontractors = DB::select('select * from subcontractors');

    return view('subcondetails', [
        'subcontractors' => $subcontractors,
        'subemployees' => $subemployees,
    ]);
}
```

You can use your Eloquent model to execute the query. The plain SQL may be incompatible if you would like to change your database in the future, and should be avoided as much as possible.

```php
public function index()
{
    $subemployees = Subemployee::all(); //Change to your model name
    $subcontractors = Subcontractor::all(); //Change to your model name

    return view('subcondetails', [
        'subcontractors' => $subcontractors,
        'subemployees' => $subemployees,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
I tried both the methods which you stated, sadly the problem still persists.
Same error "Undefined variable: subemployees (0)"